# Typescript Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

My work environment is
Nuxt.js Vue works with some typescript.

This problem occurs when for looping inside methods.

I refer to the _id in Objects
reservatsions[i].I got the result from the _id

```
methods: {
async tripdone() {
  try {
    const legnth = this.myObject.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < legnth; i++) {
      const status = this.myObject[i].status;

      const tripDate = this.myObject[i].date;
      const today = new Date();

      var year = today.getFullYear();
      var month = ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var day = ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);

      var todayString = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      if (tripDate < todayString && status === "confirmed") {
        const id = this.myObject[i]._id;
        const payload = {
          status: "tripOver",
        };

        this.$axios.put(`/api/myObject/${id}`, payload);
        const message = id;
        const type = "success";
        this.$message({ message, type });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    const message = "error";
    const type = "error";
    this.$message({ message, type });
  }
}
```

Vetur's errors in the current syntax are as follows:

`(property) reservations: ObjectConstructor`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'ObjectConstructor'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'ObjectConstructor'.Vetur(7053)

I don't know what type of error this is
I tried to understand it while looking at the `typescript`, but I couldn't solve it.

The syntax for the error is as follows

> const status = this.myObject[i].status; // string

> const tripDate = this.myObject[i].date; // string

> const id = this.myObject[i]._id; // number

In dev build, ERROR is generated, but the result was calculated and the desired result was obtained
At pm2 start,

```
ERROR in index/myObject/index.vue:360:26
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'ObjectConstructor'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
    358 |         const legnth = this.myObject.length
    359 |         for (let i = 0; i < legnth;  i++) {
  > 360 |           const status = this.myObject[i].status
        |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    361 |             // const legnth = this.myObject.length
    362 |             //  for (let t = 0; t < legnth; t++) {
    363 |           const tripDate = this.myObject[i].date

ERROR in index/myObject/index.vue:363:28
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'ObjectConstructor'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
    361 |             // const legnth = this.myObject.length
    362 |             //  for (let t = 0; t < legnth; t++) {
  > 363 |           const tripDate = this.myObject[i].date
        |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    364 |           const today = new Date()
    365 |
    366 |           var year = today.getFullYear();

ERROR in index/myObject/index.vue:377:24
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'ObjectConstructor'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
    375 |               // return tripDate < todayString
    376 |           if ( tripDate < todayString && status ==='confirmed') {
  > 377 |             const id = this.myObject[i]._id
        |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    378 |             const payload = {
    379 |               status: "tripOver"
    380 |             }
```

I seek advice on the reasons and solutions for this phenomenon

add myOject define below

```
data () {
 return{
    myObject: Object 
   }
  }
```

Comment: You can put your type inline `(this.myobject as YourType)[i]._id;`

Comment: It causes other errors.

Conversion of type 'ObjectConstructor' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.Vetur(2352)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thx to reply bill.gates

```
(this.myobject as YourType)[i]._id;
```

This form works perfectly
Instead, I put `any` in the type.
It functions as I want

```
(this.myobject as any)[i]._id;
```

Is there a problem if I put `any`?